# Exceptions for specific problems

Tags: java, exception, project

I am writing a code that causes exceptions if a file does not exist or if an invalid instruction is on the file. How do I get a code to throw an invalid instruction exception in my code

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch FileNotFoundException and then rethrow whatever exception you want. see below..

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    throw new InvalidRobotInstructionException(e);
}
```

Comment: Ok that probably would work but InvalidRobotInstructionException already extends RuntimeException in its own class.

Comment: Ok. Then i would suggest to validate you input below as per @ggreiner and throw exception accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch `InvalidRobotInstructionException`. In your while loop, you need to detect whether `String s = in.nextLine();` is an invalid instruction, if it is then you can do:

`throw new InvalidRobotInstructionException()`

Comment: How can i determine if its invalid? I really have no clue how to do that?

Comment: it's hard to know without the requirements of the program. What is an "invalid instruction"?

Comment: Any character that isnt a number or N S W or E.

Comment: what are u thinking would help?